# What difference between analytic curve, and analytic function? .

Tags: calculus, curves

What is the difference between an analytic curve, and an analytic function?

Comment: An analytic curve $\gamma : I \to \Bbb R^n$ is a map whose components $\gamma_a : I \to \Bbb R$ are analytic functions.

Comment: @Travis - I shad be grateful, If you explain with  an example.

Comment: There's not much to say really. For $n = 2$, just pick two real-analytic functions $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ on $\Bbb R$. Then, $\gamma(t) := (\gamma_1(t), \gamma_2(t))$ gives an analytic curve in $\Bbb R^2$.

Comment: @Travis - Thanks, Please see this question, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1715911/a-question-on-analytic-curve .Why is this question true?

Comment: I do not understand the question, for the same reason as discussed in the comments there.